# What is the difference between Function.caller.arguments and Function.arguments?

Tags: javascript

Is there a difference whether I use `foo.caller.arguments` or simple `arguments` inside function `foo`:

```
function foo(){
    console.log(foo.caller.arguments);
}

function foo(){
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

Comment: just belonging.

Comment: `caller.arguments`? Or `arguments.caller`? If `arguments.caller`, it's been deprecated a long time ago and nothing supports it anymore: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/caller

Comment: The [*caller* property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) is non–standard (i.e. not part of any version of ECMAScript), so should not be used.

Comment: `caller.arguments` I'm interested in

Comment: yes, I know it's not standard, I would just like to know the differences between them. I'm refactoring an old code, and I want to know if I can use simple `arguments` instead of `caller.arguments`. And also want to understand why was `caller.arguments` used there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's said in the comments to the question, `caller` is not a standard property:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller

Having said that, it returns a reference to the caller, that is, the function that has called the current function. So, `caller.arguments` gets you the arguments with which the caller has been invoked.

`arguments` gets you the arguments used in the call to the current function.

For example:

```
function one(c) {
    console.log('arguments', arguments);
    console.log('caller.arguments', one.caller.arguments);
}

function two(a, b) {
    one(3);
}

two(1, 2)
```

Prints

```
arguments [3]
caller.arguments [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

`arguments`  gives the arguments to the fuction itself whereas `caller.arguments` gives the arguments of the functions which calls this function. Following code will give you the basic understanding.

BTW `function.caller` is `Non-standard` as suggested bt MDN

```
var foo = function(name) {
  bar('second');
}

var bar = function(surname) {
  console.log(arguments);
  console.log(bar.caller.arguments)
}

foo('first');
```